# Error while connecting to a SQL Server Database: not trusted connection

Tags: sql-server-2005-express, trustedconnection

We have installed on a company a SQL Server 2005 express on a server. Some workstations connects to the server while they're using our applications with Windows Authentication.

But there's ONE computer that can't connect. When the user opens any application, it shows after a few seconds the next error:

[image: Error]

This computer is in the same workgroup that the rest of them (there's no domain, only a workgroup) and the connection string is the same that in the other ones (all shortcuts point to the same executable on the server).

Any hint?  Thank's

Comment: Maybe, turn off the computer's Firewall or antivirus just to check that no ports are being blocked.

Comment: It didn't work. Without an active firewall/antivirus the error still exists.

Anyway, our client told this morning to us that this computer had a lot of problems (not only this one) and they decided to format it. Now the error has gone (and all files too). Thank's anyway.